# ArcObjects 10.1 IDatabaseCompact lock file

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to automate one of task by creating code that will execute the `IDatabaseCompact.Compact` method to a GDB file. Everything seems to work fine but there is always a .lock file generated after the Compact method is called. I am planning to do something else after the Compact process but it errors out because of the lock file.

Is there any way to close/delete the lock file?

BTW, this is how my process works:

first, I bind and initialize my system using:

`ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop)
_ao = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.AoInitialize()   _ao.Initialize(ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic)`

I then call my compact method:

```vb
Public Sub CompressFileGDB(gdbFilePath As String)
    Dim dbCompact As IDatabaseCompact
    Dim ws As IWorkspace = FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(gdbFilePath)

    If (TypeOf ws Is IDatabaseCompact) Then
        dbCompact = CType(ws, IDatabaseCompact)
        If (dbCompact.CanCompact) Then
            Dim didFinish As Boolean = True
            Try
                dbCompact.Compact()
            Catch ex As Exception
                didFinish = False
            Finally
                dbCompact = Nothing
                ws = Nothing
                _ao.Shutdown()

                RaiseEvent OnProcessDone(didFinish)
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The compact method works, there is a significant change in the GDB file size. I also tried to set my attributes to Nothing after the process but it doesn't seem to help that much.

Answer (score 1):

After doing more research i was able to fix the issue by allowing **ComReleaser** to manage the lifetime of my IDatabaseCompact object.

For ArcObjects 10.1, the ComReleaser is in the ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Local.dll

This is the Resulting code:

```vb
    Using comReleaser As ComReleaser = New ComReleaser()
        Dim dbCompact As IDatabaseCompact
        Dim ws As IWorkspace = FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(gdbFilePath)

        If (TypeOf ws Is IDatabaseCompact) Then
            dbCompact = CType(ws, IDatabaseCompact)
            comReleaser.ManageLifetime(dbCompact)

            If (dbCompact.CanCompact) Then
                Try
                    dbCompact.Compact()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    didFinish = False
                Finally
                    dbCompact = Nothing
                    ws = Nothing

                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End Using
```

Hope this is helpful.